# What is the difference between "flabbergast" and "taken aback"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference

[Flabbergast and](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flabbergast) [taken aback](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-sb-aback?q=taken+aback), what is the difference?

1. She was **flabbergasted** when the nurse came in and gave spinal injection.
2. She was **taken aback** when the nurse came in and gave spinal injection.

As a N-NS, I understand them as the same tones used to express that someone is being surprised. Do they have any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Taken aback" is more a momentary thing, where for an instant one's brain seems to stop because the situation is so unexpected (like getting a spinal injection without prior warning!).

Being "flabbergasted" is usually longer in duration.  The person is first *taken aback*, but the strangeness seems so big and spread-out that they can't "regain their balance" for awhile.  Everything seems to be "at sixes and sevens", and they can't make sense of anything (such as why they're getting a spinal injection without prior warning!).

["Taken aback" is a term from the days of sail, when the wind might completely shift to blow from the front for a moment, which would cause the sails to fill the wrong way and the ship to be "taken aback", i.e. stopped abruptly, with an effect similar to a small earthquake.]

Answer (score 2):

MW refers to "flabbergasted" as "too astounded to respond" and "taken aback" in my thesaurus is closer to startled and is not as strong. I'm not sure why getting a spinal tap would cause this reaction. Being told I was getting one might do it though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "be flabbergasted" and "be taken aback" interchangeably.
However, the former is more informal.

Comment: More informal and more superlative, I'd say.